# Why do I see so many kinetochores?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, microscopy, fluorescent-microscopy, green-fluorescent-protein

I am analysing RPE-1 cells from humans and I do not understand why I see so many kinetochores by immunofluorescence (more than 100 in many cells). They are in prometaphase.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that they are RPE-1? Not a cell culture expert but other common cell lines are highly aneuploid (e.g. https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_many_Chromosomes_are_there_in_this_picture), and cell line contamination is very common.